# How to select text found by `re-search-forward`?

Tags: elisp, search, region

The following function searches buffer text for string `STR`, in the same way as `search-forward`. How to modify it in order that it selects the text found?

```
(defun my-search-forward (str)
  (interactive "smy-search-forward: ")
  (re-search-forward str nil t))
```

Comment: For clarification, you meant *marking* a string and not *highlighting* it (as in `hi-lock-mode`), correct? If so, I believe the question and the tag need to be updated.

Comment: @kaushalmodi Thanks, I updated the question.

Comment: There is no such thing (though you can invent it ;-)) as "marking" a string. Presumably you mean selecting text as the active [region](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mark.html). That sets the mark at one end of the text, with point at the other end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to do it:

```el
(defun my-search-forward (str)
  (interactive "smy-search-forward: ")
  (when (re-search-forward str nil t)
    (setf
     (point) (match-beginning 0)
     (mark) (match-end 0))))
```

Comment: I suggest to wrap the whole thing in a `when` form for the case nothing is matched.

Answer (score 2):

@PythonNut provided a good answer. Another answer is that if you use library [**Isearch+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus) (e.g., for other, more important reasons) then you have a user option and commands that let you select the last target occurrence (set the region around it):

- Option `isearchp-set-region-flag` -– Non-`nil` means automatically set the region around the last search target.
- Command `isearchp-toggle-set-region`, bound to `C-SPC` during Isearch -– toggle `isearchp-set-region-flag`.
- Command `set-region-around-search-target` -– manually set the region around the last search target.

So if you set the option to non-`nil` then Isearch selects the last search hit automatically, by default.

Whether the option is `nil` or non-`nil`, you can cause Isearch to select that search hit by using `C-SPC` before exiting Isearch, if needed.

And if you do not, in one of these ways, cause Isearch to automatically select the last search hit, you can nevertheless select it after exiting Isearch, by using command `set-region-around-search-target`.